# Eclipse Editor: automatically switch context when parts get active/inactive

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am developing my own eclipse editor and need to switch between different contexts for key binding. Currently I am doing the context activation/deactivation manually upon part activation.

This page
https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_advext_contexts.htm says:

> If you are activating a more specific Context within your part (either 
>       View or Editor) you can use the part site service locator to active 
>       your Context. The part's IContextService will take care of activating 
>       and deactivating the Context as your part is activated or deactivated. 
>       It will also dispose the Context when the part is disposed.

It seems like that is just what I want. But the page did not say how. Can anyone give me a hint what a 'part site service locator' mentioned in the text is and how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through Eclipse code, here's my answer to my own question.

First thing first, it is JUST enough to invoke

```
IContextService contextService = part.getSite().getService( IContextService.class );
contextService.activateContext( "your.editor.context.id" );
```

anywhere after `init`(where you get `PartSite`), just as @Rüdiger Herrmann mentioned in his answer.

AND(here's my finding) NOTHING ELSE need to be done.
Eclipse will automatically activate/deactivate the context when part is activated /deactivated, just as described in the text I refer to. In addition, when the part site is disposed, all context will be disposed.

If you are interested in how, here's more digging.

#### Activate/Deactivate

When we invoke `getSite().getService(IContextService.class)`, what we get is an instance of `SlaveContextService`.
When we call `activateContext(String contextId)` on it, our request will be automatically translate to a request with a default expression `ActivePartExpression`.

From it's name we can easily guess that this expression will check whether a part is active and do some changes. The changes it does can be seen at `ContextService.UpdateExpression.changed`. Here's the code(ContextService:124-128)

```
if (result != EvaluationResult.FALSE) {
    runExternalCode(() -> contextService.activateContext(contextId));
} else if (cached != null) {
    runExternalCode(() -> contextService.deactivateContext(contextId));
}
```

Whenever Eclipse context changes(activate/deactivate part will trigger context change), `UpdateExpression.changed` will be invoked and check whether the target part is still active, then activate/deactivate the context accordingly.

#### Dispose

In `SlaveContextService.dispose`, all context registered through it will be disposed upon the service's dispose.

Answer (score 1):

I would interpret the text so that you should use the service locator of the site that corresponds to your (editor) part. In the following example, `part` references your editor. By obtaining the context service from the part's site, you get a child context service for that particular part in wich you can activate a specialized editor context.

```java
IContextService contextService = part.getSite().getService( IContextService.class );
contextService.activateContext( "your.editor.context.id" );
```

Comment: So I just write the code you mentioned when creating my part, and do not need to deactivate the context when switching to other parts? This sounds good! I will try this.

Comment: Not sure, you may still need to activate/deactivate the context from the editor's activate and deactivate events.

Comment: I see. I will make some experiments and update the result here.